# Rolify remove_role deletes from role table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rolify

This is strange.  I'm using Rolify + CanCan + Devise in my rails 3.2 app.  My use case is simple.  I want a user to have only one role at a time, thus to change a role, I do something like this:

```
user.remove_role "admin"
user.add_role "associate"
```

The strange thing to me is that when I do this, the role "admin" gets deleted from the Roles table.  Why would this be?  I don't want to eliminate the role entirely, just a given role from the user.  What am I doing wrong?

Here's the SQL.  Notice the last delete from roles statement:

```
3] pry(main)> u.remove_role "sub_admin"
  Role Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = 2 AND "roles"."name" = 'sub_admin'
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "users_roles" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = 2 AND "users_roles"."role_id" IN (2)
   (1.9ms)  commit transaction
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "users"."id" = "users_roles"."user_id" WHERE "users_roles"."role_id" = 2
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (2.1ms)  DELETE FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."id" = ?  [["id", 2]]
   (0.6ms)  commit transaction
```

Answer (score 4):

The basic problem is that each combination if role-name, resource_type, and resource_id is stored only once in the `roles` table. If you delete this row, it is deleted for everyone.

The solution then is to delete only the rows from the `join table` of rolify connecting the `User` and the `Role` models. For ease of access i will make the join table a model to use some rails magic to generate the SQL. Since this is really a kind of service object, i will make it a class singleton.
Here is my hack:

```
class UsersRoles < ActiveRecord::Base

    def self.delete_role(subject,role_symbol, obj=nil)
        res_name = obj.nil? ? nil : obj.class.name
        res_id   = obj.id rescue nil
        role_row = subject.roles.where(name: role_symbol.to_s, resource_type: res_name , resource_id: res_id).first
        if  role_row.nil?
            raise "cannot delete nonexisting role on subject"
        end
        role_id = role_row.id
        self.delete_all(user_id: subject.id,role_id: role_id)
    end

    private_class_method :new
end
```

This code is not optimized, but should give you idea what to do: for example you can now add a convenience method to the `User` model:

```
def delete_role(role_symbol,target=nil)
    UsersRoles.delete_role self,role_symbol,target
end
```

then you can say:

```
user.delete_role :admin
```

and it will only remove what you want.

Note that this **will not** remove the table row with the role, which I would retain for future use.

Comment: Where do I put this? As a new controller?

Comment: This is not a new controller,but an Active Recrod Model for a join table, which usually dont have one.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is more than two years old, but I found better and more "rolify like" answer.
You can do it really easy in User model:

```
def remove_only_role_relation(role_name)
    roles.delete(roles.where(:name => role_name))
end
```

and use it like:

```
@user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
role_name = params[:role_name]
# or:
# role_name = Role.find_by_id(params[:role_id]).name rescue nil
if @user and role_name
    @user.remove_only_role_relation(role_name)
end
```

I found similar code in their sources:
[rolyfi: role.rb](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/rolify/3.4.0/files/lib/rolify/role.rb) - here method remove_role cals method "remove" in adapter file: [rolyfi: role_adapter.rb](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/rolify/3.4.0/files/lib/rolify/adapters/active_record/role_adapter.rb)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I resolved this issue:

## models/user.rb

```
def delete_roles
  roles.delete(roles.where(:id => self.roles.ids))
end
```

## user_controller.rb

```
def add_role
  @user.delete_roles
  role = params[:user][:roles]
  @user.add_role Role.find(role).name if not role.blank?
  @user.role_id = Role.find(role).id if not role.blank?
end
```

Every time a user is created or updated, delete the user's roles.

Answer (score -1):

Go to `config/initializers/rolify.rb`

uncomment this line

```
  config.remove_role_if_empty = false
```

so the file will look like this now:

```
Rolify.configure do |config|
  
  # Configuration to remove roles from database once the last resource is removed. Default is: true
  config.remove_role_if_empty = false
end
```

By default, remove_role_if_empty is set to `true` and rolify will delete role if it's not assigned to any other user.